# If $f(g(x)) = g(x)$, what is $f(x)$?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

> If $f(g(x)) = g(x)$ then can we conclude $f(x)=x$?
>   (In fact, $g(x) = x + 2f(x)$.)

Or which properties should $g(x)$ satisfy? (like one-to-one, etc.)

Comment: The conclusion is valid if and only if $g$ is surjective (onto). Surjective functions have a one-sided inverse: there exists a function $h$ such that $g\circ h=id$ exactly when $g$ is surjective. Your equation can be written as $f\circ g =g$. If you precompose this with $h$, you get $$f=f\circ id=f\circ (g\circ h)=(f\circ g)\circ h=g\circ h=id.$$

Comment: I've posted an answer, but wasn't sure what you mean by "In fact, $g(x) = x + 2f(x)$". Is that part of the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $f(g(x)) = g(x)$, then for any $y$ that occurs as $y = g(x)$ for some $x$, we have (by putting that particular $x$ in the equation) the fact that $f(y) = y$.

In other words, **$f$ is the identity function on the range of $g$.**

However, at values that don't occur in the range of $g$ (i.e. for values $y$ which don't occur as $y = g(x)$ for any $x$), the function $f$ could take any arbitrary value, and we would not be able to tell the difference by just considering $f(g(x)) = g(x)$, because this fact is simply agnostic and irrelevant to such values.

In the example in [marty cohen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494109/if-fgx-gx-what-is-fx/494112#494112), with $g(x) = x^2$, the range of $g$ is the nonnegative numbers (assuming that we're working over the reals or a subset thereof). So on the set of nonnegative numbers, we can say that $f(x) = x$. But $f(x)$ could take any value at all for negative numbers. His example of $f(x) = |x|$ is one where $f(x) = x$ for nonnegative numbers, but $f(x) = -x$ for negative numbers. We could also take functions like $\displaystyle f(x) = x\frac{1 + x}{1 + |x|} + (x - |x|)^3$ or indeed any arbitrary function $f$ satisfying $f(x) = x$ for nonnegative numbers.

Answer (score 5):

This is the question I am answering:

> If some functions $f$ and $g$ are such that $f(g(x)) = g(x)$ and $g(x) = x + 2f(x)$ for every $x$, can we conclude that $f(x)=x$ for every $x$? More generally, which properties should such a function $g$ satisfy, such as, being one-to-one, etc.?

If $f\circ g=g$ and $g(x)=x+2f(x)$ for every $x$ then $2f\circ g=g\circ g-g$ hence $g\circ g=3g$. Conversely, if $g\circ g=3g$, define $f$ by $f(x)=\frac12(g(x)-x)$, then $f\circ g=g$ and $g(x)=x+2f(x)$ for every $x$. This shows one is reduced to study the solutions of the functional equation  $g\circ g=3g$.

To answer succinctly the main question in the post, the obvious solution $g:x\mapsto3x$ is not the only one hence no, one cannot conclude that $f:x\mapsto x$.

For a counterexample, let $X\subset\mathbb R$ and $h:X\to \mathbb R\setminus X$ and consider the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=3x$ for every $x$ not in $X$ and $g(x)=h(x)$ for every $x$ in $X$. Then $g\circ g=3g$ but $g$ need not be the function $x\mapsto3x$, nor a regular function, nor one-to-one, nor onto.

Note that $X$ can be as large as one wants, as long as $X\ne\mathbb R$, and that $h$ can be *any* function whose image is included in $\mathbb R\setminus X$. This leaves plenty of room for "pathological" examples.

To be fully specific (while being not *too* pathological), consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x$ for every $x$ not in $\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=\frac12(\pi-x)$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the range of $g$.

For example,
if $g(x) = x^2$,
and $f(x) = |x|$,
then
$f(g(x)) = g(x)$
for all real $x$.